# <namespace name>: is not a member of 'winrt'

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I have three projects - one exe, one dll and one lib. exe depends on dll which depends on lib. I have XAML user control defined in a namespace in lib and that control is used in the MainPage.xaml in exe project. But the exe project gives compilation error `<namespace name>: is not a member of 'winrt' in XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp file`. Not sure what I am missing.

In XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp TypeInfos array is defined in which there is an entry for this control type. Please let me know if details are needed. But do not know what all I should share so not sharing it right away.

Comment: How are you consuming C++/WinRT? Are you using the Windows 10 SDK version of the headers -or- are you using the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/)?

Comment: I am using NuGet

Comment: With multiple projects, you sometimes need to add the NuGet to more than one of them. Run the NuGet manager and make sure it's added to all three.

Comment: It means you forgot to `#include <winrt/namespace_name.h>`.